# Proper XHTML syntax when using "checked" attribute?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, href

this is the error I'm getting from my IDE:

*Error: Attribute "checked" not allowed on XHTML element "a" at this point.
From line 66, column 1; to line 66, column 70*

```
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('none', 60)" checked="checked">Default style</a>
```

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm

How do I change the code to get the correct XHTML syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` elements may not have a `checked` attribute. Only `input` elements with a `type` of `radio` or `checkbox` may. It makes no sense to give a link a `checked` attribute.

- [W3C specification for the `a`
  element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-transitional.dtd_a)
- [W3C specification for the `input`
  element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-transitional.dtd_input)

Answer (score 4):

checked="checked" is not a valid attribute for an anchor tag.

How/Where to use checked="checked" :

```
<input name="nameHere" id="idHere" value="valueHere" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove "checked" and add "title"
`<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('none',60)" title="Choose Style">Default style</a>`